# From MySQL to MySQLi OR PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have a webshop with many queries on the different modules. Now I want to change MySQL to one of the two newer versions.

What's the best type to convert my existing MySQL to?

Comment: It depends up to you, we do not see sources from your page and the structure you've used before. But MySQLi is very simmilar to MySQL, just open some editor and let it rewrite in multiple files.

Comment: @WigglerJtag [there's even a tool](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi) that can help save time.